# prevent a 1*1 pixel image before </body> from creating any margin

Tags: html, css

see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vebpjny/)

I've set `<body>` to have no margins at all, yet an 1*1 image at the end of the page is creating a big margin.

adding/removing the current css reset doesn't help.

what is causing this? only way I can figure to avoid that is to set the image as invisible/hidden, but there's gotta be another way.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<img src="zzz.png" width="1" height="1"/>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 1080px;
    min-height: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    color: #FBFBFB;
    background-color: red;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
}

a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio, b, big, blockquote, button, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, dl, dt, em, fieldset, figcaption, figure, font, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, input, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, menu, nav, object, ol, p, pre, q, s, samp, section, select, small, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, textarea, tfoot, th, thead, tr, tt, u, ul, var, video {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    font-size-adjust: auto;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -o-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%}
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}

table {
    table-layout: auto;
    empty-cells: show;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Comment: What is the image for..?

Comment: why not make it `position:absolute;`?

Comment: tracking pixel that would be added with jquery according to a user action (click on some element). while running it I've noticed this side effect

Comment: Set `display: block;` to `img` - http://jsfiddle.net/jy4h69m4/

Comment: @MaryMelody works too, thanks, what's the default value?

Comment: @Yani your'e right, I don't remember why it is relative. can't understand though why it makes this happen.

Comment: just tested and changing the container to `position:absolute` doesn't solve this for IE8-10, so that's out of the equation I guess.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/6vebpjny/1/

```
<div id="container"></div>
<img src="zzz.png" width="1" height="1" style="float:left"/>
```

When in doubt float sh*t out.

Float the image left.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `line-height` of `16px` that is causing this gap to show up.

You should put this image in a spot where it won't add an additional line. Else, remove it from the layout with a `position: absolute` or by floating it as @Nicholas Young says.

Comment: do you mean `line-height:1`? does it mean `16px`? even if I change it to 0 (Which I don't wanna do, there's still some gap).
I don't remember why I've set the container div to be `position:relative`, when I change it to absolute it does solve it, as well as making the image that way. I wonder what does this position has to do with the gap?

Comment: `line-height: 1` doesn't mean `1px`, but makes it relative to the font size.

Comment: @rockyraw, Jacob is right. The nature of this gap and its relation to `line-height` are well described in this classic article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the 1x1 pixel beacon image does not open up any white space,
set the height attribute to 0 in the `img` tag and set `display: block` in the CSS.

The image will still load regardless of the height or width attributes.

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-color: green;
}
img.beacon {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<img class="beacon" src="zzz.png" width="1" height="0"/>
```